# How to add anchor tag in the string passing to checkbox in react

Tags: reactjs

How to add anchor tag in the string passing to checkbox in react

Snippet like

```
<Checkbox
  label="I have read the <a href="some site url">Terms and condition</a> and agreed it"
/>
```

Note- there can be more than one tags inside string like `<u></u>` and many more.

I don't want to create any other component for it

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do this way:
<Checkbox
  label={
   <div>
      <span>I accept the </span>
      <Link to={'/terms'}>terms of use</Link>
      <span> and </span>
      <Link to={'/privacy'}>privacy policy</Link>
   </div>
   }
 />
```

Comment: is it come in single line?

Comment: <Checkbox label={<Link to={'/yourLink'}>Your text goes here</Link>} />
hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! is it the dangerouslySetInnerHtml. anyone can cross site scripting attack possible with it